# How to convert the following excel table into a proper data table format in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I got data in the following format as an example:

[image]

However, I need the data in this format for manipulation. Please do ignore the formating as I only care about the raw data.

[image]

Would appreciate any help on this as I'm not completely familar with power Bi.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=power+query+unpivot

Comment: Select a cell in the range (table). Select `Data->From Table/Range`. The Power Query Editor window opens. Select `Transform->Unpivot Columns->Unpivot Other Columns` Using *right-click-select* handle additional modifications. When done 'playing', select `Home->Close & Load->Close & Load To...`.